# How to change page and call function at the same time?

Tags: javascript

HELP! Event onClick needs to send data to the server and change the page at the same time. Here is my code ,but data is send with method POST ,but page are not changing...

```
 const commandButton = document.getElementById("order");
  commandButton.onclick = function () {
    createOrder(); // A function that sends users data to server with POST method
    window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:5500/front/html/confirmation.html";
  };
```

```
  function createOrder() {
    const firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    const lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    const address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    const city = document.getElementById("city").value;
    const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    const newCustomer = {
      // newCustomer is an object which will be changed into string with JSON.stringify
      contact: {
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        address: address,
        city: city,
        email: email,
      },
      products: panier,
    };
```

Comment: Submitting a form starts a navigation process, during that process you can't change the navigation target. You can redirect from the server, or send the data with AJAX, then changing the location with JS would work.

Comment: There is something wrong with    `createOrder()` function. Otherwise `window.location.href` would change the pages.

Comment: @Erenn Nope, a pending submission prevents any navigation.

Comment: Please add implementation  of `createOrder` function to your question.

Comment: When the form is blank, the page changes, when the fields are filled, the page does not change...

Comment: How about when you comment out your `createOrder()` line? does it change the page?

Comment: Yes,but only with blank form. With filled form it stays the at the same page.

Comment: Your invocation of `createOrder()` indicates, in a comment, that it `,,, sends users data to server with POST method`; however the definition of `createOrder()` you've shared does not in fact do any such thing. Can you ensure that you've provided your code in accordance with our guidelines on creating a [mre]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is because you haven't prevent form from making it's own general request, try using `event.preventDefault();` in `onclick` handler to prevent form doing it's general operation and check that solves problem or not.

```
const commandButton = document.getElementById("order");
commandButton.onclick = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  createOrder(); // A function that sends users data to server with POST method
  window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:5500/front/html/confirmation.html";
};
```